# Find integer solution $|x^2-y|=8|y^2-1|$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, integers

Find integer solution $|x^2-y|=8|y^2-1|   (1) $
I try to: If $y^2-1=0$ we have $y\in\{1,-1\}$
With $y=1\Longrightarrow x=\pm 1$
$y=-1\Longrightarrow x^2+1=0$ not satisfied.
In other case: $\left| \dfrac{x^2-y}{y^2-1}\right|=8$.

But I can't to solve it.

Comment: Hint: $y=0$ gives no solution, so you have to consider $y>1$ only.  In this case $|y^2-1|=y^2-1$.

Comment: The first step is to get rid of the absolute value signs. First, find all the solutions to $x^2-y=8(y^2-1)$, then find all the solutions to $x^2-y=-8(y^2-1)$.

Comment: @Michael Hoppe, you also need to consider $y<0$.

Comment: I can't to slove continuous, can you help me to guide more details?

Comment: There are only two possiblities: $x^2-y=\pm8(y^2-1)$. Both of these give you standard quadratic diophantine equations that you should be able to solve with the standard techniques for quadratics.

Comment: As Steven said, @Hung nguyen, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by several commenters, because of the absolute values, there are only two possible cases.

*Case 1:* $x^2-y=8(1-y^2)$. Then $8y^2-y=8-x^2$. The left-hand side is greater than or equal to $7$ for all $y ≠ 0$, while the right-hand side is less than or equal to $8$ for all $x$. The only possible equalities are $7$ or $8$, and it is easily seen that $(x,y)=(\pm 1,1)$ is the only solution.

*Case 2:* $x^2-y=8(y^2-1)$. This has an infinite number of solutions, which can be found using standard quadratic methods.